# I am getting Token is invalid error in node js and react js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, nodejs-server

I am trying to create an app and I want to upload image if user is admin i am using react as front end and node js to create api and mongo db as database now my api is working properly in postmen but when i am trying to upload an image through frontend it throws this error "token is invalid" and in node js terminal i am getting this "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAdmin')"

File for token verification

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const veryfiyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.token;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json("You are not authorised");
  }
};

const veryfiyTokenAndAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  veryfiyToken(req, res, () => {
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(403).json("You are not allowed to do that");
    }
  });
};

const veryfiyTokenAndAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    veryfiyToken(req, res, () => {
      if (req.user.isAdmin) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.status(403).json("You are not allowed to do that");
      }
    });
  };

module.exports = { 
    veryfiyToken,
    veryfiyTokenAndAuthorization,
    veryfiyTokenAndAdmin };
```

File to upload image

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import { authRequest, publicRequest } from "../../../Redux/requestMethods";
import { IoCloudUpload } from "react-icons/io5";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  Flex,
  useColorMode,
  useColorModeValue,
  Input,
  Button,
  FormLabel,
  Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ProgressBar from "../ProgressBar/ProgressBar";
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { firebaseApp } from "../../../firebase.config";

export default function UploadForm() {
  const { colorMode } = useColorMode();
  const bg = useColorModeValue("gray.50", "gray.900");
  const textColor = useColorModeValue("gray.900", "gray.50");
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loading1, setLoading1] = useState(false);
  const [loading2, setLoading2] = useState(false);
  const [loading3, setLoading3] = useState(false);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const [imageAsset, setImageAsset] = useState(null);
  const [imageAsset1, setImageAsset1] = useState(null);
  const [imageAsset2, setImageAsset2] = useState(null);
  const [imageAsset3, setImageAsset3] = useState(null);

  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


  const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp); // Firebase Storage
  const firebaseDb = getFirestore(firebaseApp); // Firebase FireStore

  function handleChange(e) {
    setInputs((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    });
  }

  const token = Cookies.get('accessToken')
  console.log(token)
  
  // console.log(inputs);

  /// Thumbnail Image ///

  function UploadThumbnailImage(e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setLoading(true);
      const ThumbnailImage = e.target.files[0];

      const storageRef = ref(
        storage,
        `Images/${Date.now()}-${ThumbnailImage.name}}`
      );

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, ThumbnailImage);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapShot) => {
          const uploadProgress =
            (snapShot.bytesTransferred / snapShot.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(uploadProgress);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        async () => {
          await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setImageAsset(downloadURL);
            setInputs((prev) => {
              return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: downloadURL };
            });
          });
        }
      );
    }
  }
  /// Image - 1 ///
  function UploadImage1(e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setLoading1(true);
      const Image1 = e.target.files[0];

      const storageRef = ref(storage, `Images/${Date.now()}-${Image1.name}}`);

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, Image1);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapShot) => {
          const uploadProgress =
            (snapShot.bytesTransferred / snapShot.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(uploadProgress);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        async () => {
          await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setImageAsset1(downloadURL);
            setLoading1(false);
            setInputs((prev) => {
              return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: downloadURL };
            });
          });
        }
      );
    }
  }

  /// Image - 2 ///
  function UploadImage2(e, Image2URL) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setLoading2(true);
      const Image2 = e.target.files[0];

      const storageRef = ref(storage, `Images/${Date.now()}-${Image2.name}}`);

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, Image2);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapShot) => {
          const uploadProgress =
            (snapShot.bytesTransferred / snapShot.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(uploadProgress);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        async () => {
          await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setLoading2(false);
            setImageAsset2(downloadURL);
            setInputs((prev) => {
              return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: downloadURL };
            });
          });
        }
      );
    }
  }

  /// Image - 3 ///
  function UploadImage3(e, Image3URL) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setLoading3(true);
      const Image3 = e.target.files[0];

      const storageRef = ref(storage, `Images/${Date.now()}-${Image3.name}}`);

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, Image3);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapShot) => {
          const uploadProgress =
            (snapShot.bytesTransferred / snapShot.totalBytes) * 100;
          setProgress(uploadProgress);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        async () => {
          await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setLoading3(false);
            setImageAsset3(downloadURL);
            setInputs((prev) => {
              return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: downloadURL };
            });
          });
        }
      );
    }
  }

  async function uploadToDatabase(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await authRequest.post("/images",{...inputs },{
      withCredentials: true});
    console.log(res);
  }


  return (
    <Flex
      justifyContent={"center"}
      alignItems="center"
      width={"full"}
      minHeight="100vh"
      padding={10}
    >
      <Flex
        width={"80%"}
        height="full"
        border={"1px"}
        borderColor="gray.300"
        borderRadius={"md"}
        p="4"
        flexDirection={"column"}
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent={"center"}
        gap={2}
      >
        <Input
          variant={"flushed"}
          placeholder="Title"
          name="title"
          id="title"
          focusBorderColor="gary.400"
          isRequired
          errorBorderColor="red"
          type={"text"}
          _placeholder={{ color: "gray.500" }}
          fontSize={20}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Flex
          border={"1px"}
          borderColor="gray.500"
          height={"40px"}
          borderStyle="dashed"
          width={"full"}
          borderRadius="md"
          overflow={"hidden"}
          position="relative"
        >
          {!imageAsset ? ( // ThumbnailImage
            <FormLabel width={"full"}>
              <Flex
                direction={"column"}
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent={"center"}
                height="full"
                width={"full"}
              >
                <Flex
                  direction={"column"}
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  height="full"
                  width={"full"}
                  cursor="pointer"
                >
                  {loading ? (
                    <ProgressBar msg={"Uploading Image"} progress={progress} />
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <IoCloudUpload
                        fontSize={"8rem"}
                        color={`${colorMode == "#f1f1f1" ? "dark" : "#111"}`}
                      />
                      <Text mt={2} fontSize={20} color={"blackAlpha.700"}>
                        Click To Upload Thumbnail Image
                      </Text>
                    </>
                  )}
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
              {!loading && (
                <input
                  type={"file"}
                  name="thumbnailImg"
                  style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={UploadThumbnailImage}
                />
              )}
            </FormLabel>
          ) : (
            <Flex
              justifyContent={"center"}
              alignItems="center"
              width={"full"}
              height="full"
              position={"relative"}
            >
              <Text fontSize={20} fontWeight="bold" color={"blackAlpha.900"}>
                Image Uploaded
              </Text>
            </Flex>
          )}
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          border={"1px"}
          borderColor="gray.500"
          height={"40px"}
          borderStyle="dashed"
          width={"full"}
          borderRadius="md"
          overflow={"hidden"}
          position="relative"
        >
          {!imageAsset1 ? ( // 1st Image
            <FormLabel width={"full"}>
              <Flex
                direction={"column"}
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent={"center"}
                height="full"
                width={"full"}
              >
                <Flex
                  direction={"column"}
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  height="full"
                  width={"full"}
                  cursor="pointer"
                >
                  {loading1 ? (
                    <ProgressBar msg={"Uploading Image"} progress={progress} />
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <IoCloudUpload
                        fontSize={"8rem"}
                        color={`${colorMode == "#f1f1f1" ? "dark" : "#111"}`}
                      />
                      <Text mt={2} fontSize={20} color={"blackAlpha.700"}>
                        Click To Upload Image-1
                      </Text>
                    </>
                  )}
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
              {!loading1 && (
                <input
                  type={"file"}
                  name="img1"
                  style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={UploadImage1}
                />
              )}
            </FormLabel>
          ) : (
            <Flex
              justifyContent={"center"}
              alignItems="center"
              width={"full"}
              height="full"
              position={"relative"}
            >
              <Text fontSize={20} fontWeight="bold" color={"blackAlpha.900"}>
                Image-1 Uploaded
              </Text>
            </Flex>
          )}
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          border={"1px"}
          borderColor="gray.500"
          height={"40px"}
          borderStyle="dashed"
          width={"full"}
          borderRadius="md"
          overflow={"hidden"}
          position="relative"
        >
          {!imageAsset2 ? ( // 2nd Image
            <FormLabel width={"full"}>
              <Flex
                direction={"column"}
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent={"center"}
                height="full"
                width={"full"}
              >
                <Flex
                  direction={"column"}
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  height="full"
                  width={"full"}
                  cursor="pointer"
                >
                  {loading2 ? (
                    <ProgressBar msg={"Uploading Image"} progress={progress} />
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <IoCloudUpload
                        fontSize={"8rem"}
                        color={`${colorMode == "#f1f1f1" ? "dark" : "#111"}`}
                      />
                      <Text mt={2} fontSize={20} color={"blackAlpha.700"}>
                        Click To Upload Image-2
                      </Text>
                    </>
                  )}
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
              {!loading2 && (
                <input
                  type={"file"}
                  name="img2"
                  style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={UploadImage2}
                />
              )}
            </FormLabel>
          ) : (
            <Flex
              justifyContent={"center"}
              alignItems="center"
              width={"full"}
              height="full"
              position={"relative"}
            >
              <Text fontSize={20} fontWeight="bold" color={"blackAlpha.900"}>
                Image-2 Uploaded
              </Text>
            </Flex>
          )}
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          border={"1px"}
          borderColor="gray.500"
          height={"40px"}
          borderStyle="dashed"
          width={"full"}
          borderRadius="md"
          overflow={"hidden"}
          position="relative"
        >
          {!imageAsset3 ? ( // 3rd Image
            <FormLabel width={"full"}>
              <Flex
                direction={"column"}
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent={"center"}
                height="full"
                width={"full"}
              >
                <Flex
                  direction={"column"}
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  height="full"
                  width={"full"}
                  cursor="pointer"
                >
                  {loading3 ? (
                    <ProgressBar msg={"Uploading Image"} progress={progress} />
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <IoCloudUpload
                        fontSize={"8rem"}
                        color={`${colorMode == "#f1f1f1" ? "dark" : "#111"}`}
                      />
                      <Text mt={2} fontSize={20} color={"blackAlpha.700"}>
                        Click To Upload Image-3
                      </Text>
                    </>
                  )}
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
              {!loading3 && (
                <input
                  type={"file"}
                  name="img3"
                  style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={UploadImage3}
                />
              )}
            </FormLabel>
          ) : (
            <Flex
              justifyContent={"center"}
              alignItems="center"
              width={"full"}
              height="full"
              position={"relative"}
            >
              <Text fontSize={20} fontWeight="bold" color={"blackAlpha.900"}>
                Image-3 Uploaded
              </Text>
            </Flex>
          )}
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          direction={"column"}
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent={"center"}
          height="full"
          width={"full"}
        >
          <Input
            variant={"flushed"}
            placeholder="Description"
            name="desc"
            focusBorderColor="gary.400"
            isRequired
            errorBorderColor="red"
            type={"text"}
            _placeholder={{ color: "gray.500" }}
            fontSize={20}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          direction={"column"}
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent={"center"}
          height="full"
          width={"full"}
        >
          <Input
            variant={"flushed"}
            placeholder="Price"
            name="price"
            focusBorderColor="gary.400"
            isRequired
            errorBorderColor="red"
            type={"text"}
            _placeholder={{ color: "gray.500" }}
            fontSize={20}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          direction={"column"}
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent={"center"}
          height="full"
          width={"full"}
        >
          <Input
            variant={"flushed"}
            placeholder="Place"
            name="place"
            focusBorderColor="gary.400"
            isRequired
            errorBorderColor="red"
            type={"text"}
            _placeholder={{ color: "gray.500" }}
            fontSize={20}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          direction={"column"}
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent={"center"}
          height="full"
          width={"full"}
        >
          <Input
            variant={"flushed"}
            placeholder="Fuel Type"
            name="fueltype"
            focusBorderColor="gary.400"
            isRequired
            errorBorderColor="red"
            type={"text"}
            _placeholder={{ color: "gray.500" }}
            fontSize={20}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Flex>
        <Button
          marginTop={"1rem"}
          isLoading={loading}
          loadingText="Adding File"
          colorScheme={"teal"}
          variant={`${loading ? "outline" : "solid"}`}
          width="full"
          _hover={{ shadow: "lg" }}
          fontSize={20}
          onClick={uploadToDatabase}
        >
          Upload File
        </Button>
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
}
```

File containing authRequest

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:500/api/';

const token = Cookies.get('token')

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

export const authRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers:{
        token: `Bearer${token}`
    }
})
```

auth file which stores token in cookie and handles login

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJs = require("crypto-js");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const { findOne } = require("../models/User");

dotenv.config();
router.use(cookieParser());

// Register

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: CryptoJs.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.PASS_KEY
    ).toString(),
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

// Login

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(401).json("wrong credentials");

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJs.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_KEY
    );

    const OrignalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJs.enc.Utf8);

    OrignalPassword !== req.body.password &&
      res.status(401).json("wrong credentials");

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.JWT_KEY,
      {expiresIn:"3d"}
    );

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

    res
      .cookie("accessToken", token)
      .status(200)
      .json({ ...others, token});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);

    return;
  }

  return;
});

module.exports = router;
```

Image controller

```js
const User = require('../models/User');
const Image = require('../models/Image');

const addImage = async (req,res,next)=>{
    const newImage = new Image({ ...req.body});
    try {
        const saveImage = await newImage.save()
        res.status(200).json('Image uploaded')
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}

module.exports = Object.freeze({
    addImage
})
```

I know this is lot of code but it works perfcetly in postmen but not working in react and i cant figure out why? I tried every possible solution any help......

Comment: Can i see function "   getDownloadURL()   " ?

Comment: That is inbuilt function of firestorage after uploading file we get url for that file it is working properly in my case

Answer (score 0):

well after a lot of try I solved this I had issue with passing my token as I said it was working totally ok with postmen so below is my solution

1. Changes is authRequest method

from this

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:500/api/';

const token = Cookies.get('token')

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

export const authRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers:{
        token: `Bearer${token}`
    }
})
```

To this

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:500/api/';

const accessToken = Cookies.get('accessToken')

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

export const authRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers:{
        token:`Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
})
```

when I was trying to to get token I was using 'token' in Cookies.get() but I named it accessToken in my response so I was not getting token so changing it name gave me token.
second while passing token in header I was not providing space between Bearer and token in formated sting.
If similar problem occurs check for request in networks header tab in dev tools it helps a lot. :)

Note:- Do not pass token in request method as shown in code  authRequest instead pass it in post method as below

```js
async function uploadToDatabase(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await authRequest.post(
      "/images",
      { ...inputs },
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers:{
          token:`Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
      }
    );
  }
```